# one way -Anova plot in R with CI

Tags: r, ggplot2

I performed one-way anova

```
mydat=structure(list(Price = c(1480000L, 1480000L, 1035000L, 1480000L, 
1465000L, 689000L, 611000L, 611000L, NA, 855000L, 855000L, NA, 
1480000L, 1035000L, NA, 1465000L, 850000L), Regionname = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Eastern Victoria", "Northern Metropolitan"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Price", 
"Regionname"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

now i try create the plot

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydat, aes(x = Regionname, y = Price)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "grey80", colour = "blue") +
  scale_x_discrete() + xlab("Regionname") +
  ylab("Price")
```

But I'm completely not satisfied by this visualization

how to get plot like on this picture

[image: desired plot]

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
# make a simple regression first
s1 <- summary(lm(Price ~ Regionname + 0, mydat))  # note: w/o constant!

# of which you can create a model frame
m1 <- data.frame(coef=coef(s1)[1, 1], se=coef(s1)[1, 2], mn="Eastern Victoria")
m2 <- data.frame(coef=coef(s1)[2, 1], se=coef(s1)[2, 2], mn="Northern Metropolitan")
mf <- rbind(m1, m2)

i95 <- - qnorm((1 - .95) / 2)  # significance 95%

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mf, aes(color=mn)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=mn, y=coef, ymin=coef - se*i95, ymax=coef + se*i95), shape=0) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=mn, ymin=coef - se*i95, ymax=coef + se*i95), width=.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=coef, x=mn, group=1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=rep("dark red", 2)) +
  labs(x="Regionname", y="Price") +
  guides(color=FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

***Yields***

[image]

Comment: Great) but why here only 2 categories, there is no west metropolitain. is it okey?

Comment: There is no west metropolitan provided in your data. But adding `m3 <- data.frame(coef=coef(s1)[2, 1], se=coef(s1)[2, 2], mn="west metropolitan")` and `mf <- rbind(m1, m2, m3)` should work.

Comment: thank you. I forgot, that i didn't paste the catogory)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, The given data doesn't contain any info about the third group 'west metropolitan', hence plotted only for two groups :

```
   library(tidyverse)
    mydat %>% 
        group_by(Regionname) %>% 
    summarise( mean = mean(Price, na.rm=TRUE),#you can choose a different summay stats here like median etc.
                           sd = sd(Price, na.rm=TRUE),
                           n = n(),
                           se=sd/sqrt(n),
                           ci = qt(0.975, df=n-1)*se) %>% ##I have taken 95% Confidence interval, you can decide yourself
        ggplot(aes(x=Regionname, y=mean, group = factor(1))) +
        geom_line() + ##connecting lines between the error bars
        geom_point() + 
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-ci, ymax=mean+ci), width=.1) + ##Errorbar instead of boxplot as per your requirement
        ggtitle("Figure Mean Score by Regionname")
```

[image]